# Throttle per IP in WSO2 API Manager 2.1

Tags: wso2, ip-address, wso2-api-manager, throttling

I use use WSO2 API Manager 2.1 and I would like to make a throttle per caller IP, that is to say for each IP address, and not for a specify IP address.

Example :

API context : /weather
No authentication (no oauth token)
No application

Client 1 : 
IP address : 218.12.1.19

Client 2 : 
IP address : 218.12.1.20

Throttle expected : 10 req / min / IP

If "Client 1" make more than 10 calls to the API in the minute, their calls will be throttled but "Client 2" can make their 10 calls without be throttled.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable in WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0. Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Adding+New+Throttling+Policies

Comment: Thank you for your response but this documentation describes how to throttle one IP address (or a range of IP address). My need is to throttle any IP address without specifying one in particular.